# word to abstract top and bottom just like "side" abstracts left and right

Tags: american-english, terminology

Think about a ball, it has its sides and its ...

The sides obviously refers to left and right positions, but what about top and bottom positions, is there a word to abstract them?

If there exists such a word, I'd like to know.

Comment: Actually, a ball, being a sphere, doesn't have sides.  Or it has infinite sides.  But as for your question, I don't think that such a word exists in english.  The best I can offer is "horizontal surfaces", which works for some objects.

Comment: In fact I thought of a snooker ball, which you can hit with side spin or the vertical spin (that I want to know the name)

Comment: You could say north, south, east, west.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a general term for the upper and lower parts of an object.

If you are just interested in terms for spin for snooker, I have a couple of comments.

With sidespin, it is not all that important to specify the direction, but with top and bottom it generally is important, because of the respective effects on the ball are completely different: it is therefore important to have separate terms for these two techniques.

The term topspin is used when you strike the top of the cue ball, and backspin/screw shot when you strike the bottom half of the cure ball.

The term backspin is more appropriate to racquet games, where you can apply such a strong backspin that the ball doesn't reach your opponent, instead coming back to you. Generally with snooker you don't want the cue ball to start coming back until after it has hit another ball.

Answer (score 2):

A sphere that rotates, or a ball that spins, does so about an axis. The two points at which the axis meets the surface of the sphere are called poles. So the poles are in that sense the top and bottom of the sphere, or ball. But I don't think that in everyday English you could just use the word poles without some explanation unless the ball in question were the earth.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few words for this. One word you can use is "half." For a ball, you hit it on the bottom or top half.  Similarly, when speaking about a person's body, you would say something like, "She was standing in the pool so I only saw the top half of her body." You can also use "part" if "half" seems inaccurate. Example: When slicing a pineapple, you should cut the top and bottom parts off first. Finally, people also simply say "the top" or "the bottom." Example: I could feel something crawling on the bottom of my foot.